# Akka actorSelection reconnect after failure

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have an actor, that watches over another actor (which is remote, therefore it can not be referenced directly). It obtains a reference to the actor by using `actorSelection` and `Identify` and then watches the resulting `ActorRef`. That works.

But now I want to automatically reconnect as when the other actor terminates, so I reuse the same `actorSelection` (The Actor get's instantiated at the same location), but this time the lookup via `Identify` fails forever. I have no clue, why it works, when the actor is already instantiated at the beginning but not, otherwise.

**Edit:** *Whats also Strange is that before the first connect there are association errors whereas when trying to reconnect there are not, even though the remote jvm is completely terminated. I just noticed that if you wait about a Minute or longer after the failure, the association error return and the connection succeeds again. Is there maybe a way to configure this (is it a Cache?) mechanism.*

Is that standard behaviour or did I get something wrong?

In case I messed something up with my Code:

```
object ServerMonitor {
  case object Request
  case class Reply(ref: ActorRef)
}

class ServerMonitor(path: String) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import ServerMonitor._

  var server: Option[ActorRef] = None  
  var listeners: Set[ActorRef] = Set.empty

  def receive = {
    case ActorIdentity("server", Some(ref)) =>
      server = Some(ref)
      context.watch(ref)
      listeners.foreach(_ ! Reply(ref))
      listeners = Set.empty
      log.info(s"connected to the server at $path")

    case ActorIdentity("server", None) =>
      server = None
      log.warning(s"couldnt reach the server at $path")
      import context.dispatcher
      context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(1 second) {
        context.actorSelection(path) ! Identify("server")
      }

    case Terminated(ref) =>
      log.warning("server terminated")
      server = None
      context.actorSelection(path) ! Identify("server")

    case Request =>
      server.fold { 
        listeners += sender
      } { ref =>
        sender ! Reply(ref)
      }
  }

  override def preStart() {
    context.actorSelection(path) ! Identify("server")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I just found out, what the Problem is. There is a configuration value:

```
# The length of time to gate an address whose name lookup has failed
# or has explicitly signalled that it will not accept connections
# (remote system is shutting down or the requesting system is quarantined).
# No connection attempts will be made to an address while it remains
# gated. Any messages sent to a gated address will be directed to dead
# letters instead. Name lookups are costly, and the time to recovery
# is typically large, therefore this setting should be a value in the
# order of seconds or minutes.
gate-invalid-addresses-for = 60 s
```

Which can be set to low, to allow quick reconnects after recovery of the remote system. 60s seems rediculously high to me even when considering the stated reasons.